py2app: how to have Python script request permissions to access microphone?
This line works fine when the Python script is run from the command-line:
recording = sounddevice.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=1, dtype='float64')

But when compiled with py2app, no sound is ever recorded. I suspect the issue is that the app is not asking the OS for permission to access the system microphone, but I can't figure out any way to trust the app or to force it to ask for permission.
Any ideas?
